# jquery function path directory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function and i'm trying to point to specific path and for some reason its giving me an

```
Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

JQuery Code

```
$.getJSON( variableThatHoldsDirectoryToJsonFile, function(data) {
```

The variable has a path of

```
'C:\firstFolder\secondFolder\myfile.json'
```

When i inspect the page and go to the line where it givens an error it prints out

```
$.getJSON('C:\firstFolder\secondFolder\myfile.json', function(data) {
```

Comment: Try **file://firstFolder/secondFolder/myfile.json**

Comment: You need to escape the `\` character: `'C:\\firstFolder\\secondFolder\\myfile.json'